# Como o Laravel 5 faz para que uma instância seja passada automaticamente, se apenas definirmos o Type Hinting no parâmetro numa função?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Creio que essa seja uma curiosidade totalmente válida, visto que isso facilita muito e agiliza o desenvolvimento.

Costumo sempre analisar o código dos frameworks que costumo usar, como o `Cakephp 2`, `Laravel 4` e `Symfony 2`.

Comecei a trabalhar a pouco tempo com o `Laravel 5` e percebi que nele há uma funcionalidade que nunca vi em nenhum dos frameworks. É a **passagem automática de uma instância para o argumento de um método** de um controller ou rota, ou qualquer outro classe do framework, simplesmente ao definir o `Type Hiting` da função.

Exemplo:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(Request $request, UrlGenerator $url)
    {
       $request->get('nome');
    }
}
```

Ao fazer isso nos parâmetros de `getIndex`, automaticamente, são passados isso para o método as instâncias das classes. Assim, se eu não quiser usar o `UrlGenerator`, posso simplesmente remover a declaração de parâmetro desse método, que ele não será passado por argumento.

Ou seja, não importa a posição dos parâmetros, ele sempre me dá a instância do argumento tipado simplesmente porque eu passei ele lá.

Outro exemplo:

```
 public function getIndex($id, Request $request){}
```

Ou

```
public function getIndex(Request $request, $id) {}
```

Como é possível fazer isso em php? Como é que o `Laravel` faz isso?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54622/discussion-on-question-by-wallace-maxters-como-o-laravel-5-faz-para-que-uma-inst)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso só é possível graças ao [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container) do Laravel. Ele é uma implementação de patterns de *IoC* (*Inversion of Control*) e *DI* (*Dependency Injection*) que tem como objetivo reduzir o acoplamento entre as classes e facilitar na construção de objetos.

Ele resolve as classes de duas formas: Através de um *binding*, que é uma espécie de configuração onde informamos qual a instância deve ser retornado se determinada classe for injetada:

```
<?php 

app()->bind(MinhaClasse::class, function () {
    return new MinhaClasse(new OutraClasse, 'algum-argumento');
});
```

Basicamente aqui estamos registrando no *Service Container* o que ele deve retornar ao instanciar uma classe específica. Isso pode ser utilizador para amarrar em nosso código uma implementação específica de uma Interface.
Esses *bindings* são escritos geralmente nas classes de [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers) do Laravel.

A segunda forma é similar a primeira e o Laravel usa a *Refletion API* do PHP para instanciar esses classes. Porém isso não vai funcionar com Interfaces e com classes que tem dependências no construtor que também não podem ser resolvidos pelo *Service Container* (uma *string* com a key de API, ou uma interface sem *binding* por exemplo).

Isso torna possível que todas as classes que são executadas **dentro** do possam injetar no momento da instanciação da classe as dependências necessárias.

Basicamente o Laravel recorre ao Service Container e solicita aquela classe. Por baixo dos panos o Laravel na verdade faz isso:

```
<?php 

app()->make(MinhaClasse::class);
```

Essa forma de trabalhar não é exclusiva do Laravel. Existe outras implementações de Dependency Injection em outros frameworks, como o [Zend/Di](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.di.quick-start.html) ou o [thephpleague/container](https://github.com/thephpleague/container).

Para ter uma ideia de como fazer, você pode se inspirar nessa classe:
https://github.com/thephpleague/container/blob/master/src/ReflectionContainer.php

Comment: O método `resolveClass` é quem faz o trabalho no `Laravel`. A classe `Container` é que faz toda a mágica ;).