# Conflito IoC Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, construtor, injeção-de-dependência

Tenho os seguintes códigos:

Chat Staff Service

```
namespace Chat\Api\V1\Services\Chat;

class ChatStaffService extends Service
{

     private $chatService;

     public function __construct(ChatService $chatService)
     {
         $this->chatService = $chatService;
     }

     ...
}
```

Chat Service

```
namespace Chat\Api\V1\Services\Chat;

class ChatService extends Service
{
     private $chatStaffService;

     public function __construct(ChatStaffService $chatStaffService)
     {

         $this->chatStaffService = $chatStaffService;
     }

     ...
}
```

O que está acontecendo:
No desenvolvimento de uma API em um certo momento utilizo de funções do ChatStaffService no ChatService e em outros momento preciso usar funções do ChatService no ChatStaffService. Quando eu coloco a dependência em qualquer um dos constructors a aplicação simplesmente para e volta erro 500. Quando retiro a dependência e tento usar uma função que não necessite dela tudo volta a funcionar normalmente.

Preciso de alguma idéia para contornar este problema. Tentei desenvolver a seguinte função para resolver o problema mas não funcionou.

```
     function checkAndInject($anInstance, $injection)
     {
         if($anInstance == true)
            return $injection;
         else
            return \App::make($injection);
     }
```

Comment: Pode colocar `namespace` e porque precisa usar um dentro do outro, acredito que o problema esteja nesse aspecto

Comment: Adicionei o namespace

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers já fez isso? ou/e isso http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116115/como-o-laravel-5-faz-para-que-uma-inst%C3%A2ncia-seja-passada-automaticamente-se-ape/116213#116213, ou seja, já registrou esses classes para que o Laravel suba?

Comment: Sim sim, ja fiz isso, acontece a mesma coisa. Estou pensando em fazer uma super classe e abstrair as funcionalidades. Mas eu queria uma solução mais elegante do que esta.

Comment: Olha é complicado saber porque está dando erro 500 sem ver o código na sua totalidade. Fazer uma classe não garante que vai solucionar seu problema, talvez sanar esse erro, mas, você deve encontrar o porque disso, o que você fez para isso acontecesse ...

Comment: O problema é que a aplicação não retorna absolutamente nada, nem em log. Ja tentei de tudo, só dá erro 500.

Comment: Porque tem erros na codificação, o Laravel só funciona com todo o conjunto de classes estão funcionando corretamente, se tiver faltando uma virgula não roda...

Comment: O problema é que os 2 services estão funcionando a quase um ano sem nenhum problema. A unica coisa que fiz agora foi injetar ai parou de funcionar.

Comment: Pode ser pela programação interna, pode ser por uma chamar a outro e isso está violando algo, é tanta coisas que é dificil sem ver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no design das suas classes. É simplesmente impossível instanciar qualquer uma das classes pois uma depende da outra. Se fosse construí-las manualmente, como seria?

```
$chat = new ChatService(new ChatStaffService(new ChatService(...)));
```

É exatamente isso que o Laravel faz, tendendo ao infinito, até o PHP quebrar.

E o que você pode fazer nesse caso? Repense a estrutura das suas classes. A classe `ChatStaffService` me parece ser uma especialização de `ChatService`, então implemente de forma mais genérica a classe `ChatService`, de modo que não dependa de nada com `ChatStaffService`.

`ChatStaffService` pode ser uma herança simples de `ChatService`, assim ele consegue utilizar os métodos do `ChatService` e caso faça algo diferente basta ele sobrescrever o método.

Com isso você não precisa injetar nada no construtor.

```
// ChatService    
namespace Chat\Api\V1\Services\Chat;

class ChatService extends Service
{
     private $chatStaffService;

     public function __construct()
     {

         //
     }

}

// ChatStaffService
namespace Chat\Api\V1\Services\Chat;

class ChatStaffService extends ChatService
{
     public function __construct()
     {
         //
     }

}
```